# Discord.js how my bot can send a message in fonction of time?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I'm developing a little bot but I'm blocking. I would like for example as soon as it is 12:00 noon he send me a message. I tried to create a parallel program but I still can't send myself a message.

My parallel script :

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const client = new Discord.Client();
const moment = require("moment");
const cheerio = require("cheerio"); 
const request = require("request");

const prefix = 'dolores ';
const fs = require('fs')
const myip = "";
const queue = new Map();
var currentdate = new Date();

client.once('ready', () => {
    console.log('Event activate : My Body is Ready');
});

myip.send(`test`);


client.login("");
```

Comment: You can try npm cron

Comment: you can't login without a bot token. not to mention you never sent a message using `client`. and the fact that you can't do `"string".send()`

Comment: I have delete my Token for privacy but I don't understand how send a message like this automaticly in private.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off, you need to figure out what method you wish to use to do something at `X` time.

#### Option 1

This is my preferred method.

```js
function checkIfNearby(){
    let rightNow = new Date();
    let timeNow = (rightNow.getHours() * oneHour) + (rightNow.getMinutes() * 60000) + (rightNow.getSeconds() * 1000);
    if(timeNow < timeToRun && timeNow+oneHour >= timeToRun){//are within a hour's window
        setTimeout(function(){
            //DO ACTION
        },timeToRun - timeNow);
    }else{
        setTimeout(checkIfNearby,oneHour);//check again in a hour.
    }
}
client.on("ready",function(){
    checkIfNearby();
});
```

#### Option 2

The other way is to just replace the `checkIfNearby` with this:

```js
function checkIfNearby(){
    let rightNow = new Date();
    let timeNow = (rightNow.getHours() * oneHour) + (rightNow.getMinutes() * 60000) + (rightNow.getSeconds() * 1000);
    setTimeout(function(){
        //DO ACTION
    }, timeToRun - timeNow);
}
```

## Getting the person to send the message.

So when we run `//DO ACTION` we need to send a message to our person (in this case, you). What we'll need is the user's ID and the following:

```js
let user;
client.on("ready", function(){
    client.users.fetch("<USER-ID-HERE>").then((fetched) => user = fetched);
}).catch(console.error);
```

And now in place of `//DO ACTION` just have `if(user)user.send("Hey, it's now time");`

## Note:

This works, only once. So once it send the message, it won't do it again. To have it repeat, include a `checkIfNearby()` AFTER you run `//DO ACTION`

Comment: I apologize, According to https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/v12/class/UserManager?scrollTo=fetch `UserManager.fetch()` returns a promise not a user. I've updated the sample code to reflect this.

Comment: Make sure that the `client.users.fetch` is being ran, as `user` starts off as `undefined` then gets set when we run the `client.on("ready")`. It may take time to fetch, or it just WONT fetch if you don't put in a valid ID, put in a `.catch` after the `.then` to see if it errors.